# udev not running rule at boot?

Tags: symlink, udev

I have a very simple udev rule at `/etc/udev/rules.d/sdcard.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="mmcblk1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SYMLINK+="sdCARD"
```

Problem is the symlink is not created for me automatically at boot. I have many other rules and all them work just fine at boot (my symlinks are created).

However, if I run this then the symlink IS created:

```
udevadm test /block/mmcblk1
```

What could be going on here? Why isn't it created at boot? Could the device not be available yet? How could I find that out?

---

**Update One**

---

Output of udevadm:

```
 looking at device '/block/mmcblk1':
    KERNEL=="mmcblk1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="3862528"
    ATTR{stat}=="       9        0       74        0        1        0        8        0        0        0        0"
    ATTR{range}=="8"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{force_ro}=="0"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="8"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="10"
```

Comment: What if you use _last rule_... something like: `KERNEL=="mmcblk[0-9]", SYMLINK+="sdcard-%k", OPTIONS="last_rule"` ?

Comment: @don_crissti Just tried it out, doesn't seem to make a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Rename the rules file to: `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-sdcard.rules` , possibly some rules are required to run before it.

Comment: Tested just now - didn't appear to make a difference. I am so stumped on this problem.

Comment: @dtmland , Could I ask what hardware setup you are using? Could you post output of `udevadm info --name=/block/mmcblk1 --attribute-walk`?

Comment: @dtmland, you run it with `--attribute-walk` I don't see any parent device. What's this hardware/embedded system ?

Comment: Yes, I ran it with the walk attribute. I believe the mmcblk1 is the parent device? It's on unreleased SAMA5D3 based hardware.

Comment: @dtmland , I think that block device is added too early before `udevd` can catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Check that

1. the boot environment has udev enabled
2. that the newly created udev rules are included in the Linux boot environment.

For example (#2) for Arch Linux requires `$ mkinitpio -P` to update the boot initramfs image.