# How to skip boot time custom udev rule?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, usb, udev

I have following `udev` `rule` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-foo_usb.rules` to detect pen drives,

```
KERNEL=="[a-z][a-z][a-z][1-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM+="/test/foo.sh $kernel $parent"
```

It just works fine except some false positives, it get executed many times after boot. How can I skip boot time executions for this rule?

*This question is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187995/90535)*

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I modified my `udev` `rule` to check `DEVPATH` with some `regex` as:

```
KERNEL=="[a-z][a-z][a-z][1-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", DEVPATH=="*[/]usb[1-9][/]*", PROGRAM+="/opt/MicroWorld/bin/foo.sh $kernel $parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add an initial match phrase to run a program to determine whether to enable the rule or not. Though I'm not exactly sure how you'd want to determine whether it's "boot time" (rule disabled) or not (rule enabled). Other than that, the actual udev line addition would look like the following:

```
PROGRAM="/usr/local/bin/notboottime",KERNEL....
```

Check `man udev` for details on this match key.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, it is also possible to check if it is boot time call in `/test/foo.sh` passed to `PROGRAM`, but I am searching some other solution exist in `udev`